# How to enable menuitems on a ContextMenu - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I'm trying to create a ContextMenu on a UserControl derived object. Note: This is NOT a WinForms App, it is pure WPF.

So I create the ContextMenu thus:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="cmLCD_CopyCutPaste">
            <MenuItem Name="CutOption"  Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Popup_Cut}" Command="Cut" Click="MenuItem_Cut" IsEnabled="True"/>
            <MenuItem Name="CopyOption" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Popup_Copy}" Command="Copy" Click="MenuItem_Copy" IsEnabled="True"/>
            <MenuItem Name="PasteOption" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Popup_Paste}" Command="Paste" Click="MenuItem_Paste" IsEnabled="True"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

The mousebutton event is setup thus:

```
d:DesignHeight="66" d:DesignWidth="340" Focusable="True" KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown" MouseRightButtonDown="EMS_UI_LCDscreen_MouseRightButtonDown" >
```

In the code behind, the constructor starts like this:

```
        public EMS_UI_LCDscreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Find the ContextMenu created on this object - it is called cmLCD_CopyCutPaste
            ContextMenu cm = FindResource("cmLCD_CopyCutPaste") as ContextMenu;

            // If we found the contextMenu, assign it the ContextMenu placeholder for this instance.
            if (cm != null)
            {
                ContextMenu = cm;
            }

            ...
```

The mouse click(right button) is handled like this:

```
        private void EMS_UI_LCDscreen_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.ContextMenu is ContextMenu cm)
            {
                if (cm != null)
                {
                    if (DataContext is DeviceEditorData ded)
                    {
                        cm.DataContext = ded.Device.GetStructuredLocation(0);

                        cm.IsEnabled = true;

                        cm.PlacementTarget = sender as Button;
                        cm.IsOpen = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

There are the three event handlers to actually respond to the user selection on the ContextMenu:

```
        private void MenuItem_Cut(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void MenuItem_Copy(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void MenuItem_Paste(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

[View of the ContextMenu being shown on the LCD Image component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzRJV.png)

The component I have created appears in a few different contexts, but the one I'm mainly interested in is inside of a DataGrid that shows various items of data, each with one of these components. when right clicked, the component faithfully displays the popup context menu as expected..... BUT all the items on the menu are grayed out and basically not enabled.
So my question is, what is the missing piece of glue that effectively enables the menu items so that they can be clicked to do the required actions. Most of the answers already seen on the net go into detail of how to do it in a WinForms app, but despite hours of searching, I can find no clear solution to what should be a very simple task of enabling the menu items.
Can some kind soul please put me out of my anguish and in a few lines of code show me how to do it! Thank you

UPDATE: This is the XAML implementation for the LCD Component:

```
<UserControl x:Class="EMS_Config_Tool.UIComponents.WPF.EMS_UI_LCDscreen"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:p="clr-namespace:EMS_Config_Tool.Properties"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="66" d:DesignWidth="340" Focusable="True" KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown" MouseRightButtonDown="EMS_UI_LCDscreen_MouseRightButtonDown" >

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="cmLCD_CopyCutPaste">
            <MenuItem Name="CutOption"  Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Popup_Cut}" Command="{Binding Cut}"/>
            <MenuItem Name="CopyOption" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Popup_Copy}" Command="{Binding Copy}"/>
            <MenuItem Name="PasteOption" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Popup_Paste}" Command="{Binding Paste}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <UserControl.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Cut"
                        CanExecute="CutCommand_CanExecute"
                        Executed="CutCommand_Executed" />

        <CommandBinding Command="Copy"
                        CanExecute="CopyCommand_CanExecute"
                        Executed="CopyCommand_Executed" />
        
        <CommandBinding Command="Paste"
                        CanExecute="PasteCommand_CanExecute"
                        Executed="PasteCommand_Executed" />
    </UserControl.CommandBindings>

</UserControl>
```

As can be seen, it is very simple - there are no items added to the control - it only serves as a Canvas upon which the code behind draws all the needed items which are purely graphic "draw" items.

This is the implementations of the 6 methods referenced, in the corresponding .cs file for the xaml above:

```
        private void CutCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Verify relevant conditions and set CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs.CanExecute accordingly
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }
        private void CutCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Execute the command action
            if (sender is EMS_UI_LCDscreen lcd)
            {
                if (TheDevice != null)
                {
                    Clipboard.SetDataObject(TheDevice.GetStructuredLocation(0).ToString());

                    TheDevice.SetLocation(0, "");

                    lcd.StructuredTextToShow = TheDevice.GetStructuredLocation(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    Clipboard.SetDataObject(lcd.StructuredTextToShow.ToString());

                    lcd.StructuredTextToShow.SetString("");
                }
            }
        }
        private void CopyCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Verify relevant conditions and set CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs.CanExecute accordingly
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }
        private void CopyCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Execute the command action
            if (sender is EMS_UI_LCDscreen lcd)
            {
                if (TheDevice!=null)
                    Clipboard.SetDataObject(TheDevice.GetStructuredLocation(0).ToString());
                else
                    Clipboard.SetDataObject(lcd.StructuredTextToShow.ToString());
            }
        }
        private void PasteCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Verify relevant conditions and set CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs.CanExecute accordingly
            IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

            // Is the Data Text?  
            if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
                e.CanExecute = true;
            else
                e.CanExecute = false;
        }
        private void PasteCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Execute the command action
            if (sender is EMS_UI_LCDscreen lcd)
            {
                // Retrieves data  
                IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

                // Is the Data Text?  
                if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
                {
                    if (TheDevice != null)
                    {
                        TheDevice.SetLocation(0, (string)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Text));

                        lcd.StructuredTextToShow = TheDevice.GetStructuredLocation(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lcd.StructuredTextToShow.SetString((string)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Text));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Finally, the ContextMenu is assigned to the object in the constructor:

```
        public EMS_UI_LCDscreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Find the ContextMenu created on this object - it is called cmLCD_CopyCutPaste
            ContextMenu cm = FindResource("cmLCD_CopyCutPaste") as ContextMenu;

            // If we found the contextMenu, assign it the ContextMenu placeholder for this instance.
            if (cm != null)
            {
                ContextMenu = cm;
            }

            ...
```

The menu is shown on the component in response to right-click, the cut/copy/paste methods respond to the key ops, but clicking on the menu items does not fire the corresponding methods.
I can't see why that should be so, it all looks correct to me, but perhaps there is something missing that is preventing it working. One suggestion was to use a "relay command" type of thingy, but what and how that may be, is unclear.

Comment: Does your view has a view model (`DataContext`) or you use code behind?

Comment: The data context is set in the code behind. The component data context is set when the component is instantiated at runtime to the date element used to create the data row in the data grid. This is done in the code behind as it is much easier to do it that way. Generally, I use the WPF mainly for layout, the business is in the code...

Answer (score 2):

You should remove all code that sets `IsEnabled` to `true`. It's redundant as the value is `true` by default.

The buttons are disabled because you have (accidentally?) attached a command to the `MenuItem.Command` property but no corresponding command handler.
The framework will try to invoke a `CanExecute` handler. Since there is no one defined, a default handler is returned that sets `CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs.CanExecute` to `false`, which will disable the button (`ICommandSource`).

Not sure if your intention was to use a command here or you wrongfully guessed the `Command` property is like a name property (since you have also registered `Click` event handlers). See [Commanding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to learn more.

Anyway, this is how you can register a command handler:

You have assigned predefined application commands (cut, copy and paste - the `MenuItem.Command` string values in your XAML implicitly references the static [`ApplicationCommands`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.applicationcommands?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) commands). These commands are *routed commands* (behavior is identical to routed events - in fact *routed commands* are routed events). Therefore, you must define the command bindings on a parent element of the command source (the element that invokes the command) as the command will bubble up the tree.

A `UIElement.CommandBinding` consists of the specified `CommandBinding.Executed` handler and the *optional* `CommandBinding.CanExecute` handler.
Use the `CanExecute` handler to control the disabled states of the command source e.g., a `Button`. If the command source should be always enabled, simply omit the `CanExecute` handler.

**XAML**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Cut"
                    CanExecute="CutCommand_CanExecute"
                    Executed="CutCommand_Executed" />
  </Window.CommandBindings>
</Window>
```

**C#**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    var cutCommandBinding = 
      new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Cut, CutCommand_Executed, CutCommand_CanExecute)
    this.CommandBindings.Add(cutCommandBinding);
  }
}
```

Then create the corresponding command handlers in the code-behind.

```cs
private void CutCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // Verify relevant conditions and set CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs.CanExecute accordingly
  e.CanExecute = true;
}

private void CutCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // Execute the command action
}
```

---

### Update

To force command handling on the `UserControl`, you can explicitly set the `MenuItem.CommandTarget` property to reference the `UserControl`.
You can also assign the `UserControl.Contextmenu` from XAML:

```xml
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="CommandTarget"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget}" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <UserControl.Contextmenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Name="CutOption"  Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Popup_Cut}" Command="{Binding Cut}"/>
            <MenuItem Name="CopyOption" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Popup_Copy}" Command="{Binding Copy}"/>
            <MenuItem Name="PasteOption" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Popup_Paste}" Command="{Binding Paste}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </UserControl.Contextmenu>

    <UserControl.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Cut"
                        CanExecute="CutCommand_CanExecute"
                        Executed="CutCommand_Executed" />

        <CommandBinding Command="Copy"
                        CanExecute="CopyCommand_CanExecute"
                        Executed="CopyCommand_Executed" />
        
        <CommandBinding Command="Paste"
                        CanExecute="PasteCommand_CanExecute"
                        Executed="PasteCommand_Executed" />
    </UserControl.CommandBindings>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems clear enough. So I have tried it both ways, fist setting the command bindings in the code behind, and then doing it in the XAML. Both work as far as getting the menu items to be enabled (although in both cases the CanExecute methods are not called?). Besides that, clicking on the menu options does not result in my handlers getting called, so I am again missing some obvious step, so obvious that it is not mentioned in your suggestion as everybody should know it.... But thank you for pointing me in the right direction, it does help!

Comment: Usually the handlers are invoked, of course. Would you mind to add your current implementation to your question  so that I can review it?

Comment: I'm of the opinion that what I seek to do basically just isn't possible. In every example of a ContextMenu it is always in relation to some or other UI element, eg a TextBox or a Button. In my case there is no such UI element to attach the menu to. The object here is a UserControl. There are NO UI components on it, not even a Canvas as such. All elements shown on the UserControl are drawn using the OnRender method which passes in a DrawingContext on which everything is drawn. I suspect that this fundamentally excludes the use of a ContextMenu. It does show the menu, but the commands won't work

Comment: The menu must be part of the visual tree, otherwise the routed events can't traverse. Why do you drwaw all controls  manually in OnRender? This is not WinForms. YOu should add the visuals explicitly to the visual tree and not draw them manually. WPF uses a tree structure to build the GUI. If just render a random control, it will have no parent and therefore is not part of the UI tree. You will lose a lot of WPF features. Maybe I misunderstood you? In your example you were clearly retrieving the ContextMenu from a resource to attach it to a control.

Comment: Don't render controls manually. Add all controls to the UserControl.Content property, preferably using XAML. Let WPF do its job by parsing the XAML to construct and render the visual tree and delegate routed events and routed commands.

Comment: At least assign the ContextMenu to the UserControl that is the actual context. then add the handlers to its code-behind. This should do it. The UserControl will then be able to control the rendering itself and to interact with the menu.

Comment: Is it possible to concede at least that there were VERY good reasons to render this control the way it has been done, rather than simply by omission as seems to be implied. Never the less, you can see in the second sets of code that the assignment of the ContextMenu is handled in the object constructor immediately after the InitializeComponent statement. This works as expected, as shown in the graphic image sent with the original post, so that is not at issue here. There is indeed a visual tree, even if it is not populated by conventional WPF controls. It has a drawing context. Thanks anyway.

Comment: To have done this particular control using native WPF components would have been very much more complicated, which entirely negates any possible benefit provided by the use of such UI elements. However, the missing glue here would seem to be an omission in the framework to permit controls to interact with the native messaging and command structure except through native UI controls. If you had perhaps seen the image sent, the control emulates a LCD display of an embedded product, and the customer requirement was to mimic this as closely as possible. This control seeks to do just that.

Comment: I didn't meant to offend you. It sounded just weird to implement a UserControl by relying completely on OnRender. I just visioned you rendering Grid controls etc manually, so I just wanted to drop the suggestion to use Onrender only when necessary. I had implemented a digital clock face that has the classic 7 digit segments. I simply extended Shape for this task to create the segments. I then rendered those shapes using a Canvas. The advatage is that you get full WPF support like input events. Performance is not an issue. It is definitely not an issue for you either.

Comment: Obviously you are using DrawingVisual. So you would have to implement all the hit testing yourself. Anyway, to trigger the menu item command handling you must move the focus inside the UserControl. This will trigger CanExecute and the buttons will enable themselves. It would be nice if you could post a very tiny failing example that I can test. I didn't need the rendered content. Or does it work when you add a control to the UserControl?

Comment: Again there must be something inside the control that is visible for hit testing in order to get the UserControl focused. Maybe render a transparent Border as the UserControl background. This should do it. Just make sure the background is set explicitly to Transparent. Setting UserControl.background to Transparent could be sufficient. Although the rendered digital drawing will cover up the background due to the z-index. I'm afraid you can't get around to implement hit testing for your drawings - or use Shape and Canvas (the simple way).

Comment: Thanks. The component needs to encapsulate 80 separate "controls"  eg Canvas or similar. As far as I know WPF doesn't have the syntax to add such an amount as two nested loops, so it would have to be done in the code behind anyway....

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide you another workaround for your UserControl. It's basically forcing the command routing to start at your UserControl. Hope this helps.

Comment: By the way, RelayCommand (or a ICommand implementation in general) would also work. The command would then be defined in the veiw model class (or in the DataContext of the ContextMenu/UserControl in general).

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution that finally worked for me. The elixir was assigning the commands, not with the "Binding" term, but directly:

```
<UserControl x:Class="EMS_Config_Tool.UIComponents.WPF.EMS_UI_LCDscreen"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:p="clr-namespace:EMS_Config_Tool.Properties"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="66" d:DesignWidth="340" Focusable="True" KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown" MouseRightButtonDown="EMS_UI_LCDscreen_MouseRightButtonDown" >

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="CommandTarget"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget}" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <UserControl.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Name="CutOption"  Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Popup_Cut}" Command="Cut" />
            <MenuItem Name="CopyOption" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Popup_Copy}" Command="Copy" />
            <MenuItem Name="PasteOption" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Popup_Paste}" Command="Paste" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </UserControl.ContextMenu>

    <UserControl.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Cut"
                        CanExecute="CutCommand_CanExecute"
                        Executed="CutCommand_Executed" />

        <CommandBinding Command="Copy"
                        CanExecute="CopyCommand_CanExecute"
                        Executed="CopyCommand_Executed" />

        <CommandBinding Command="Paste"
                        CanExecute="PasteCommand_CanExecute"
                        Executed="PasteCommand_Executed" />
    </UserControl.CommandBindings>

</UserControl>
```

The constructor and assignment of images looks like this:

```
        public EMS_UI_LCDscreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Image ObjImage1 = new Image();
            Image ObjImage2 = new Image();
            Image ObjImage3 = new Image();

            ObjImage1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Graphics\Misc Icons\Cut.png"));
            CutOption.Icon   = ObjImage1;

            ObjImage2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Graphics\Misc Icons\Copy.png"));
            CopyOption.Icon  = ObjImage2;

            ObjImage3.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Graphics\Misc Icons\Paste.png"));
            PasteOption.Icon = ObjImage3;

            ...
```

... and displaying the context menu on the component in response to the mouse right click:

```
        private void EMS_UI_LCDscreen_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ContextMenu is ContextMenu cm)
            {
                if (DataContext is DeviceEditorData ded)
                {
                    cm.DataContext = ded.Device.GetStructuredLocation((uint)LocationIndex);

                    cm.IsEnabled = true;

                    cm.PlacementTarget = sender as EMS_UI_LCDscreen;
                    cm.IsOpen = true;
                }
                if (DataContext is EMSBasicDevice dev)
                {
                    cm.DataContext = dev.GetStructuredLocation((uint)LocationIndex);

                    cm.IsEnabled = true;

                    cm.PlacementTarget = sender as EMS_UI_LCDscreen;
                    cm.IsOpen = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

For brevity, I have not shown the ..._CanExecute / ...Executed methods, they are as shown previously in the question.

Thanks to all who have helped in resolving this issue.

[View of the finished context Menu in situ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9Z0X.png)

Answer (score 0):

So, if you are using `DataContext` and `Binding`'s, you can do the following

- remove the direct control with event handlers, i.e. `Click`, and direct setting of `Enabled`.
- use `Binding` to bind menu action to the handler inside the view model: `Command={Binding CutCommand}` (or any other handler).
- use `ICommand.CanExecute` of the command handler (`CutCommand` in the sample above). to manage `Enabled` state of menu item.

So, let's put all together.

In the XAML

```
<MenuItem Name="CutOption"  Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Popup_Cut}" 
    Command="{Binding CutCommand}"/>
```

In the ViewModel

```
class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public ICommand CutCommand { get; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        //you can just omit second arg if you always can call Cut.
        CutCommand = new RelayCommand(CutHandler, ()=>CanCut())); 
    }
    ...
}
```

Here `RelayCommand` is a https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/relaycommand or any other implementation of simple command.

If you need to update the `Enabled` state on-the-fly, you can call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();` to reevaluate `CanExecute` of *all* commands.

Comment: In the View Model? Sorry, I have no idea what you are telling me to do! Is this "ViewModel" a placeholder for the name of the class in which I'm trying to enact a context model, or is this an extra class I must now add to my class that implements the rest of the code to produce this component? Sorry to be slow here...

Comment: `ViewModel` class here is a view model in terms of MVVM pattern, or simply a object, which is a `DataContext` for the view.

Comment: Tried to install the Mvvm package, got told it doesn't support .NET4 which is my target platform.... so dumped that idea.